# Difference between keras.metrics.Accuracy() and "accuracy"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have been testing different approaches in building nn models (tensorflow, keras) and I saw that there was something strange with metric during compile model.

I checked two ways:

```
    model.compile(
        loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        metrics=keras.metrics.Accuracy()
    )
```

and

```
    model.compile(
        loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        metrics=["accuracy"]
    )
```

Result of first approach:

```
    Epoch 1/2
    1875/1875 - 2s - loss: 0.0494 - accuracy: 0.0020
    Epoch 2/2
    1875/1875 - 2s - loss: 0.0401 - accuracy: 0.0030

    <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f9c00bc06d8>
```

Result of second approach:

```
    Epoch 1/2
    1875/1875 - 2s - loss: 0.0368 - accuracy: 0.9884
    Epoch 2/2
    1875/1875 - 2s - loss: 0.0303 - accuracy: 0.9913

    <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f9bfd7d35c0>
```

This is quite strange, I thought that "accuracy" is exactly the same as keras.metrics.Accuracy().
At least this is the case in arguments "loss" and "optimizer", e.g. "adam" is the same as keras.optimizers.Adam().
Does anybody know why is this so weird or I missed something?

Edit:

Approach with metric in [] gives strange results too:

```
    model.compile(
        loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        metrics=[keras.metrics.Accuracy()]
    )

    Epoch 1/2
    1875/1875 - 2s - loss: 0.2996 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
    Epoch 2/2
    1875/1875 - 2s - loss: 0.1431 - accuracy: 1.8333e-05

    <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f9bfd1045f8>
```

Comment: try `metrics=[keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy]`

Answer (score 18):

When you are mentioning `keras.metrics.Accuracy()` you are explicitly asking the library to calculate the metric `Accuracy` which is simple comparison between how many target values matches the predicted values.

However, when you mention the string `accuracy` then depending on the type of loss you have chosen a different `Metric` gets selected. This is what is mentioned in the documentation of Keras,

`When you pass the strings 'accuracy' or 'acc', we convert this to one of tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy, tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy, tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy based on the loss function used and the model output shape. We do a similar conversion for the strings 'crossentropy' and 'ce' as well.`

Hence, as `CategoricalCrossEntropy` is the loss so `CategoricalAccuracy` gets calculated in case 2. This is based on finding argmax and then comparing the one-hot encoding. As a result, you are seeing better accuracy values in case 2 and very bad in case 1.

So the string `accuracy` will not always mean the metric function `Accuracy()`.

The explanation of different metrics for reference, https://keras.io/api/metrics/accuracy_metrics/

The explanation of argument `metrics` for reference,
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have to specify your metrics into a list. Try this :

```
model.compile(
        loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        metrics=[keras.metrics.Accuracy()]
    )
```

and you should get the same results.

Edit :

`keras.metrics.Accuracy()` calculates the accuracy between the **equality** of the predition and the ground truth [(see doc)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy). In your case, you want to calculate the accuracy of the **match** in the correct class. So you should use `keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()`or `keras.metrics.CategroicalAccuracy()` according to your problem.

Comment: I thought that too, but it does not solve the issue - I edited my post

Comment: Indeed, I checked documentation and Accuracy() calculate the number of times labels and pred are equals (not the match, but the same value) so the accuracy is almost equal to 0. So, if you want to calculate accuracy with the correct match to the label, you should try BinaryAccuracy() (or Categorical Accuracy()). I edit my answer.